# Using the same object in every instance of a class C++

Tags: c++, oop, mbed

Im trying to build a library in MBED for the nextion lcd.
It uses serial uart to connect to a microcontoller.

for this i made a class that has the methodes to communicate to the lcd. But now i want to make separate classes for buttons,sliders,etc. these should all use the same object of the serial communication class.

Whats the best way to do this?

Comment: create one object and use that? this question seems to be fishing for a sigleton, but you dont need one. Simply use one instance of the serial communication class and use that everywhere. Not really clear what is the problem

Comment: yes a sigleton is what im looking for. thanks

Comment: @arnevandenbroeck If just one singleton is responsible for representing every piece of hardware you have it sort of defeats the point of using an object oriented approach in the first place. A typical object oriented approach would be to have an object representing just one piece of hardware each.

Comment: hum.. I was trying to suggest that you do **not** need a singleton. If you want to use a single instance just do it. singleton is the most overrated patttern I know (and actually it isnt that high rated ;)

Answer (score 1):

Have your other classes ( lcd, buttons, sliders ) all take in a reference to this “same object” in their constructors.  But did you mean they should all use their own instance of the same serial class?